# Getting data into ViewModel by calling datalayer

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I'm trying to get stored data from an SQLite database into a simple textbox but I keep getting null. When the datalayer gets called the data loads correctly at first but at some point it turns null again and I can't figure out where or why it goes wrong.

Here's my ViewModel

```
public class FirstReadViewModel : NotifyUIBase
{    
    private string _scriptNotes;
    public string ScriptNotes    //binded in the View
    {
        get { return _scriptNotes; }
        set { _scriptNotes = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ScriptNotes"); }
    }

    public FirstReadViewModel()
    {
        var dbFunctions = new DataLayer();
        dbFunctions.GetFirstReadNotes();
    } 
}
```

The DataLayer

```
public void GetFirstReadNotes()
{
    String dbConnectionString = @"Data Source =DB.sqlite";

    SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnectionString);
    cnn.Open();

    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT* FROM projects WHERE projectID = 1";

    SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
         string ScriptNotes = reader["scriptnotes"].ToString();
    }
    reader.Close();
    cnn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: there must be some line of code elsewhere setting the textbox to an empty string

Comment: The statement `string ScriptNotes` inside the while loop hides the property `ScriptNotes`. Remove `string` from this statement.

Comment: I tried to paste the code of the datalayer directly in the constructor and then it holds the value.

Comment: Where are you setting ScriptNotes  in your constructor? Also, what is the usage of variable `string ScriptNotes`  in `while` loop? Since, you want to read only the first row then you should be using `if(reader.Read())` and returns the string variable (instead of void). And the correct line in your constructor will be like `this.ScriptNotes = dbFunctions.GetFirstReadNotes();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data layer method should be as follows as you want to return only first notes :

```
public string GetFirstReadNotes()
{
    string scriptNotes = string.Empty;
    String dbConnectionString = @"Data Source =DB.sqlite";

    SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnectionString);
    cnn.Open();

    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT* FROM projects WHERE projectID = 1";

    SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if(reader.Read())
    {
         scriptNotes = reader["scriptnotes"].ToString();
    }
    reader.Close();
    cnn.Close();
    }
    return scriptNotes;
}
```

And `FirstReadViewModel` as follows :

```
public FirstReadViewModel()
{
        var dbFunctions = new DataLayer();
        this.ScriptNotes = dbFunctions.GetFirstReadNotes();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should inject your `DataLayer` in your `FirstReadViewModel` by using an interface and also change your code a little bit

create a interface

```
interface IFirstReadViewModelDAL
{
    string GetFirstReadNotes();
}
```

use it, and also make use of the using function

```
   internal class DataLayer: IFirstReadViewModelDAL
    {
        public string GetFirstReadNotes()
        {
            string ScriptNotes;
            String dbConnectionString = @"Data Source =DB.sqlite";

            using(SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnectionString))
            {
                cnn.Open();

                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT* FROM projects WHERE projectID = 1";

                using (SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        ScriptNotes = reader["scriptnotes"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

            return ScriptNotes;
        }
    }
```

inject your `DataLayer` by using the interface

```
    private IFirstReadViewModelDAL dbFunctions;

    private string _scriptNotes;
    public string ScriptNotes    //binded in the View
    {
        get { return _scriptNotes; }
        set { _scriptNotes = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ScriptNotes"); }
    }

    public FirstReadViewModel(IFirstReadViewModelDAL injectDAL)
    {
        dbFunctions = injectDAL;
    }

    private void LoadData();
    {
        // use your dbFunctions
    }
```

to inject it you are needing a separate class, something like

```
public class Controller
{
    public static FirstReadViewModel getNewFirstReadViewModel()
    {
        var dal = new DataLayer();
        var vm = new FirstReadViewModel(dal);

        return vm;
    }
}
```